# Function is not working in React outside render()

Tags: reactjs

My function is not working outside the react render function. When I use function code without the function inside the render then it works. Where I am doing the mistake.

React:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state={
    calcKeys:[
     {
       "key": "AC",
      },
      {
        "key": "CE",
      },
      {
        "key": "±",
       },
       {
        "key": "/",
        },
        {
         "key": "7",
        },
       ]
      };
      this.displayKeys = this.displayKeys.bind(this);
   }
   displayKeys() {
     <div className="display-keys"> 
       <div className="screen">
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
             {this.state.calcKeys.map(item=>
                <button>{item.key}</button>
             )}
      </div>
   }
   render() {
     return(
       <div className="display-container">
         <displayKeys />
       </div> 
     );
    }
} 
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add return keyword to displayKeys

```
displayKeys() {
     return <div className="display-keys"> 
     //...
    </div>
}
```

And use this sintax for call inner render function: `{this.displayKeys()}` instead of `<displayKeys/>`.

Don't use `<displayKeys/>` because React will treat it as a independent component. If you do, then extract displayKeys on other component. E.g:

```
const Keys = ({calcKeys})=>(<div className="display-keys"> 
  <div className="screen">
     <input type="text" />
  </div>
  {calcKeys.map(item=><button>{item.key}</button>)}
</div>)

class App extends Component{
//...
  render(){
     return(
       <div className="display-container">
         <Keys calcKeys={this.state.calcKeys}/>
       </div> 
     );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the return keyword?

Comment: Yes, I aded. displayKeys() {
    return (
      <div className="display-keys"> 
          <div className="screen">
            <input type="text" />
          </div>
    {this.state.calcKeys.map(item=>
              <button key={item.key}>{item.key}</button>
          )}
        </div>
    );
   }

Comment: My mistake, I just realized that App is not a functional component. I already corrected my answer, use `{this.displayKeys ()}` instead of `{displayKeys ()}`

Comment: Thank you it worked. Also when <function /> is used?

Comment: Probably, but don't do it. I edit my answer for more details